# If my index page has no textual content, should it be present in sitemap?

Tags: seo, sitemap, search-engine-indexing

My index page contains no textual content at all (except some footer links, copyright notice and some stuff in  tag). It has, however, big Google's map with some pins attached which lead to articles. Of course this is the page I want to pop up in search results when user types my site name into Google.

In this case, should I add my index page to sitemap.xml? Thanks for any help. (Sorry, I can't paste link to this site yet.)

Comment: You kind of answer the question yourself when you say, "Of course this is the page I want to pop up in search results when user types my site name into Google." - I'm curious, however, as to why you think that not including your index page in your sitemap might be desirable? (TBH, it probably doesn't make much of a difference if your index page is included in your sitemap or not.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should definitely add it to the sitemap. It's the most important page of your website. Most websites usually have thinner content on the mainpage, but it's not a problem.